# PDF to image on Node JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, node.js

Anyone know of any good libs for NodeJS or even an API to create images out of PDF pages?

Comment: I am wondering who downvoted this question and why.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution should use external program like ghostscript to build your jpg from.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r144 -sOutputFile=p%03d.jpg file.pdf' , function(err) {
    if (err) {
        // something went wrong
    } else {
       // everything went good do something after the process is completed
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on ghost script, it seems I'm one step further on my quest to solve this problem :)